# Emit TypeScript modules as separate JavaScript files

Tags: typescript, webpack, ts-loader

I'm authoring a library and I want to provide both a bundle (where all files are compiled together) *and* a `js` folder where each module is emitted separately with its `.d.ts` file next to it. My goal is to allow:

1. Using separate files as TS modules from the `src` folder
2. Using files as JS modules from the `js` folder when you don't want to compile TypeScript
3. Using the bundle when you don't want to compile anything at all

---

I'm using [*ts-loader*](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader) to compile a bunch of TypeScript modules with the following *webpack.config.js*:

```js
let path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './src/index.ts'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'js')
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

...and the following *tsconfig.json*:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "js",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable"
    ],
    "declaration": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true
  }
}
```

With this setup, running `webpack` results in a bundle and all `.d.ts` files in a `js` folder, which is in the middle of what I want. I need each `.ts` file in the dependency graph to be emitted next to its `.d.ts` file as a `.js` file instead. Essentially, I need two Webpack configs:

- one that emits `.js` and `.d.ts` files in a directory structure that mirrors `src`
- another one that emits just a bundle

Before publish, I run both configurations and I get all I need. However, I can't get *ts-loader* to emit separate `.js` files. Is it possible?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah, I don't know why it's `es3` either. It made no sense. Changed it to `es5`. Thanks!

Comment: What is the answer for this question? Did you solve it?

Comment: I have asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74238861/how-preserve-project-structure-when-compiling-from-typescript) with no answer either.